# How to map array of dates to elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an array of dates and I want to create the mapping by Nest.
But my current mapping searches do not work. Query sample is:

```
publicationDates: '1995-01-11'
```

My mapping:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "doc-index", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class DocumentIndex
{
    [Keyword(Index = false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Text]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Date(Format = "yyyy-MM-dd")]
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> PublicationDates { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Format` parameter tells Elasticsearch how to parse the incoming string into a `date` on the server side, but it doesn't affect the way that `DateTime` are serialized by the client, which serializes `DateTime` to ISO8601 format using Json.NET internal `DateTime` serialization handling.

If you'd like to serialize `DateTime` for your POCO differently, the easiest way is to implement a `JsonConverter` and attribute the `PublicationDates` property to use this converter. This is all that is needed for NEST 5.x and previous.

In NEST 6.x, the Json.NET dependency is internalized, so if you're using NEST 6.x, you need to also use the [NEST.JsonNetSerializer package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/) and [hook up the serializer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html) so that serialization of your types is delegated to Json.NET.

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours trying to work out this problem. I kept getting an `UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException` error with 'invalid datetime format'. Adding `sourceSerializer: (x, y) => new JsonNetSerializer(x, y)` to my `ConnectionSettings` constructor fixed it for me.